# Cannot multiply a variable with concatenated word count

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have something like this in bash on Linux:

```
some_variable= ls *somepattern* | xargs cat | wc -c
```

And i would like to multiply that by some amount like:

```
another_variable = $(($some_variable * 10))
```

But i get an error

```
  -bash: * 100: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* 100")
```

Why is it not possible to not multiply `some_variable` with `wc`?

Comment: Run your script through shellcheck at shellcheck.net. As posted, it contains several errors. Also, which shell are you in? You probably need a shebang, even if only to let shellcheck know what syntax applies. I can't figure why the error message shows a number 100 which does not appear in your commands.

Comment: shellcheck came up with seven errors on those two lines. It will save you (and us) a lot of time in future.

Answer (score 5):

You never get to the multiplication, you aren't actually assigning a variable there. You can't have a space around the `=`, you need:

```
some_variable=some_value
```

Next, if you want to assign a variable to the *output* of a command, you ned to use command substitution:

```
some_variable=$(some_command)
```

Or, the still supported but becoming deprecated backticks:

```
some_variable=`some_command`
```

So, what you wanted was:

```
some_variable=$(ls *somepattern* | xargs cat | wc -c)
```

But that would be much better done like this:

```
some_variable=$(cat *somepattern* | wc -c)
```

Once you have that, you can do:

```
another_variable=$(($some_variable * 10))
```

---

Finally, your error was caused because, as explained in the first section, your variable was empty, so you ended up running this:

```
$ another_variable = $(( * 10))
bash: * 10: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* 10")
```

Comment: Also notice multiplying by 10 will have the same effect of `another_variable=${some_variable}0`.